# Copy or move a group of sheets that contain a table

Tags: vba, excel

I need to copy a group of sheets in Excel and past them into another Excel file. I have VBA code as follows:

```
Sheets(Array("COVER", "A", "B", "C")).Select
Sheets(Array("COVER", "A", "B", "C")).Copy
```

but I get an error message when I run the macro:

```
vba you cannot copy or move a group of sheets that contain a table
```

As the error states, I have some tables in the sheets. Is there as way to overcome this error?

Comment: Copy the sheets individually?  Just did a `Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=Sheets(1)` on a sheet with sample tables and sample charts and it went just fine by itself.

Comment: Also no need to "Select".  If you use `Select` then you can use `Selection.Copy` technically.

Comment: @Chrismas007, actually, `Selection.Copy` will not work in this case.  You'd have to use `ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Copy`.

Comment: You are correct. @jbarker2160 then that first line of code `.select` is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

thanks for the comments. I have resolved this question as follows:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Add
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("COVER").Copy After:=wb.Sheets(1)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("A").Copy After:=wb.Sheets(2)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("B").Copy After:=wb.Sheets(3)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("C").Copy After:=wb.Sheets(4)
Set wb = Nothing

Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Select
'Sheets("Sheet3").Activate
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Hope it helps someone else

Thanks

Comment: Thanks,  this worked for me after the approach on Microsoft's blog (#1 google result) did not work. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2009/08/31/copying-worksheets-with-a-list-or-table/